# Populate text box with JavaScript on PageLoad

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html

I have a text box called txtName on my form.

In my page I know I need to place the code in my HEAD tag like so......

```
<script type='text/javascript' language="javascript">

 document.FormName.txtName.value = "Robert";

 </script>
```

But I cant seem to set a value to my textbox txtName with the above code......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because your code get executed before the DOM is created.
You can do something like this

```
window.onload = function() { 
  document.forms['FormName'].elements['txtName'].value = "Robert";
}
```

or use JQuery

```
$(function() {
  document.forms['FormName'].elements['txtName'].value = "Robert";
  // for a shorter syntax use id
  $('#txtNameId').val("Robert");
}
```

Comment: Inside a <script> tag. If you want to use the JQuery solution you also have to add a <script> to load jquery. Take a look on its site: http://jquery.com
Double check that your for is <form name="FormName"> and your text is <input name="txtName">.
Another syntax you can use (but not a "standard" one) is
document.FormName.txtName.value = "Robert"

Comment: Inside <script> tag yes I know, but must it all go in the <head> tag? Because it still does not work......

Comment: Ok I see you also use an ID on your text.
Place this in your <head> and it must work:
<script type='text/javascript' language="javascript">
window.onload = function() { 
  document.getElementById('txtName').value = "Robert";
}
</script>

Comment: There must be something wrong with the window.onload because even when i place a alert in like so alert("Hello World"); it does not want to show the alert....

Comment: http://pastebin.com/XPjTUe6Y
This works for me. Try to see if you spot any difference/mistake...

Comment: Then there's something wrong in the page. If you need a hand post a new question and full source of the page.

Comment: You're using jquery so use this:
$(function() {
  $('#txtName').val('Robert');
});
but you have to move your <script> below the one which loads jquery.

Comment: I found the problem!!! There was another damn window.onload!! Thanks for all your help! You rock man!

Comment: Nice! If you need to have many onload do this:
oldonload = window.onload;
window.onload = function() { <your code here>; oldonload(); }

Comment: Of course for this to work, it must be the last <script> in your page. But for simplicity if you need many onload events use jquery which handles this problem (and many others) quite well.

Answer (score 1):

Your script executed before page loaded. Use onload event

Answer (score 0):

Can you set the id on the textbox?  Then you can use getElementByID("textboxid");  Selecting by id is faster.

UPDATE:
You need to ensure that the DOM has been load so that your script can locate the element you want to update.  One way is:

```
<body>      
    <form>
    <input id="txtName" name="txtaaaName" type="text" value="notnow"/>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function LoadTextBox(){
            document.getElementById("txtName").value = "ready to go";
        }

        LoadTextBox();
    </script>   
</body>
```

An alternative could be where you use onload in the body tag:

```
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function LoadTextBox(){
                document.getElementById("txtName").value = "ready to go";
            }
        </script>   
    </head>
    <body onload="LoadTextBox">     
        <form>
        <input id="txtName" name="txtaaaName" type="text" value="notnow"/>
        </form>

    </body>
```